# Use AWS CDK to Create an RDS Instance in an ISOLATED Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk

I'm trying to use CDK (Typescript) to create an RDS (Postgres) instance within an ISOLATED subnet. As far as I understood, the default VPC created automatically in each of my account regions only has Public Subnets.

If I then want to launch a Fargate instance on top of one of those Public Subnets, do I need to create a VPC Peering between the ISOLATED subnet and the default VPC?

Any idea how to create that using CDK?

Comment: There is an open bug about this - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3356#issuecomment-591669951
As you can see I suffered the same thing and ended up using private subnet

Comment: I see, thank you. So did you end up going the same route I'm describing above? Namely creating a separate VPC with a private subnet and creating VPC Peering, or else did you go about another way?

Comment: I have tested the private subnet and it fits my requirements. ( of course I would rather work this isolated)

Answer (score 1):

"Any idea how to create that using CDK?" -> yes:

1. Use AWS CDK to provision a **new** VPC similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#advanced-subnet-configuration). As you can see, there are subnets for public, applicational and database layers;
2. [OPTIONAL] For a better AWS CDK project organization, you can use multiple stacks like network (VPC resources), compute (Fargate resources), and database (RDS). You can [pass the vpc on network stack to compute & database stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#sharing-vpcs-between-stacks);
3. Be sure that you [set vpc on the ECS cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html#clusters) and [at load-balanced level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ecs-readme.html#include-an-application-network-load-balancer) (if applicable) and put [RDS database in the isolated/database by using `vpcSubnets` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-rds-readme.html#starting-a-clustered-database)

To sum up, one VPC. No applicational or database exposed to the public. [I have a git repo in case you want to look for sample code/template](https://github.com/rfpedrosa/aws-cdk)

Answer (score 0):

VPC peering is when you have two VPC with different CIDR ranges. You have one VPC hence no need to use VPC peering.